# What is this R error in bipartite package: 'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

Tags: r, bipartite

Trying to compute c and z statistics using the bipartite package in R and plot the two on a graph (c on the x-axis and z on the y-axis). I have a plant-pollinator network and I am trying to determine the most important plants in the network using the following code:

```
#calculating c and z values. c = connection z = participation
#insects
cz.insects <- czvalues(all.mod, weighted=TRUE, level="higher")
#plants
cz.plants <- czvalues(all.mod, weighted=TRUE, level="lower")
```

When I use the function czvalues() I get 6 identical warning messages and am wondering what I am doing wrong:

```
1: In dim(slot(moduleWebObject, "originalWeb")) == 0 || dim(slot(moduleWebObject,  :
  'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

Thanks!

I am not sure what to do because I researched the warning message and do not know how to fit it. I notice that some of the data points return as NA on the z-values. For example, look at the head() of my czvalues output. the z-values return a number of NAs.

```
> head(cz.plants)

$c
      ACMI       ASFA       BADE       CECY       CEIN       COAR       CRAT       CRIN 
0.34113810 0.17572333 0.09283695 0.10081873 0.49398836 0.69166726 0.00000000 0.50696682 
      DICO       ERCO       FRAL       HISC       LONU       LOTR       LUSU       SEIN 
0.69485228 0.60391999 0.34644387 0.06568726 0.16474358 0.18742946 0.29405213 0.15277778 
      TOPA       TOVE       TRGR       VISA 
0.59259259 0.00000000 0.48000000 0.00000000 

$z
      ACMI       ASFA       BADE       CECY       CEIN       COAR       CRAT       CRIN 
        NA         NA  0.7071068         NA         NA -0.7572719 -0.7071068  0.7071068 
      DICO       ERCO       FRAL       HISC       LONU       LOTR       LUSU       SEIN 
-0.3762842  1.1335561  1.1532389         NA         NA -0.5263202         NA         NA 
      TOPA       TOVE       TRGR       VISA 
-0.6269187         NA -0.7071068         NA
```

Comment: The examples in their documenation page of `czvalues` return the same type of error.  It may be better to raise an issue in their github page